# AWS Athena Table Data Update

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, pyathena

I have started testing out AWS Athena, and it so far looks good. One problem I am having is about the updating of data in a table.

Here is the scenario: In order to update the data for a given date in the table, I am basically emptying out the S3 bucket that contains the CSV files, and uploading the new files to become the updated data source. However, the period of time during which the bucket is empty (i.e. when the old source is deleted and new source is being uploaded) actually is a bottleneck, because during this interval, anyone querying the table will get no result.

Is there a way around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Is new data adheres the same table schema, i.e. same number of columns and type of information, same data types etc?

Answer (score 1):

Athena is a web service that allows to query data which resides on AWS S3. In order to run queries, Athena needs to now table schema and where to look for data on S3. All this information is stored in AWS Glue Meta Data catalog. This essentially means that each time you get a new data you simply need to upload a new csv file onto S3.

Let's assume that you get new data everyday at midnight and you store them in an S3 bucket:

```
my-data-bucket
├── data-file-2019-01-01.csv
├── data-file-2019-01-02.csv
└── data-file-2019-01-03.csv
```

and each of these files looks like:

```
| date       | volume  | product | price |
|------------|---------|---------|-------|
| 2019-01-01 | 100     | apple   | 10    |
| 2019-01-01 | 200     | orange  | 50    |
| 2019-01-01 | 50      | cherry  | 100   |
```

Then after you have uploaded them to AWS S3 you can use the following DDL statement in order to define table

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `my_table`(
  `date` timestamp, 
  `volume` int, 
  `product` string, 
  `price` double)
LOCATION
  's3://my-s3-bucket/'
-- Additional table properties
```

Now when you get a new file `data-file-2019-01-04.csv` and you upload it to the same location as other files, Athena would be able to query new data as well.

```
my-data-bucket
├── data-file-2019-01-01.csv
├── data-file-2019-01-02.csv
├── data-file-2019-01-03.csv
└── data-file-2019-01-04.csv
```

### Update 2019-09-19

If your scenario is when you need to updated data in the S3 bucket, then you can try to combine [views](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/views.html), tables and keeping different versions of data

Let's say you have `table_v1` that queries data in **s3://my-data-bucket/v1/** location. You [create a view](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-view.html) for `table_v1` which can be seen as a wrapper of some sort:

```sql
CREATE VIEW `my_table_view` AS
SELECT *
FROM `table_v1`
```

Now your users could use `my_table` to query data in **s3://my-data-bucket/v1/** instead of `table_v1`. When you want to update data, you can simply upload it to **s3://my-data-bucket/v2/** and define table `table_v2`. Next, you need to update your `my_table_view` view since all queries are run against it:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `my_table_view` AS
SELECT *
FROM `table_v2`
```

After this is done, you can drop `table_v1` and delete files from `s3://my-data-bucket/v1/`. Provided that data schema hasn't changed, all queries that ran against `my_table_view` view while it was based on `table_v1` should still be valid and succeed after `my_table_view` got replaced.

I don't know what would the downtime of replacing a view, but I'd expect it to less then a second, which is definitely less that the time it takes to upload new files.

Comment: The question is about the scenario when I need to update the data in the S3 bucket.

Comment: Does this mean that data schema would stay the same?  I have update my answer, although I haven't tested it. But intuition tells me that with the use of views (and redefining them) this should work

Comment: Your answer is goood. Although, i am not sure how this will be applicable to a partitioned table in athena. Each partition has its own sub bucket, which contains a bunch of files.

Comment: A view in Amazon Athena is a logical, not a physical table. The query that defines a view runs each time the view is referenced in a query. Also, AWS docs in seciton [When to Use Views?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/when-to-use-views.html) says that you may want to create a views in order to _hide the underlying table and column names, and minimize maintenance problems_, which seems like your case.

Answer (score 0):

What most people want to do is probably `MSCK REPAIR TABLE <table_name>`.

This updates the metadata if you have added more files in the location, but it is only available if you table has partitions.

You might also want to do this with a Glue Crawler which can be scheduled to refresh the table with new data.

[Relevant documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/creating-tables.html).